# How to prevent printing loss at each step while using the tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I am training using the Tensorflow Object Detection API in Google Colab. I want to suppress printing the loss at each step as the web page crashes after 30 minutes due to a large amount of text being printed as the output of the cell. I have to manually clear the output of the cell every 30 minutes or so to avoid this issue. Is there any way to modify the `train.py` code so that Tensorflow stops printing the loss at every step. I have tried changing the code in line 57 of the `research/object_detection/legacy/train.py` from `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)` to `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.WARN)` but it did not seem to work. Any suggestions/workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `;` if thats the print statement at the end of the print statement

Add `%%capture` in the first line of the cell for no print for the cell

and for speficic function

`from IPython.utils import io`

`with io.capture_output() as captured:
    function()`